# Returning all errors

Tags: r, function, error-handling

Let's say that I have the following function structure (a simplified version of my real problem):

```
simple_function <- function(x, y) {
  if (!is.numeric(x) && is.numeric(y)) {
    stop("x must be a number")
  }
  else if (!is.numeric(y)) {
    stop("y must be a number")
  }
  else if (is.numeric(x) && is.numeric(y)) {
    result <- sub_fun(x, y)
  }
  return(result)
}

sub_func <- function(x) {
  if (x > 5) {
    result <- x * y
  }
  else if (x < 5) {
    result <- x + y
  }
  else if (x == 5) {
    stop ("x cannot be equal to 5.")
  }
  return(result)
}

a = 5
b = 'b'
> simple_function(a, b) : y must be a number
```

Is there a way to run the function(s) in such a way that I get both relevant stop errors that would have run if it did not quit at the first stop that y must be a number?

Comment: When you call `stop()`, that's it: the function ends. No more code is run. If that's not what you want, then collect errors in some sort of list and only if that list is non-empty then call stop and combine all the errors together. R only allows you to throw one error at a time.

Comment: … you went a bit too far: *some* whitespace increases readability. The issue was having empty lines between *all* lines, not having judicious whitespace to structure the flow of the code.

Comment: Regarding you issue, I think you are thinking way too complicated: if your function has preconditions that should all be checked, *check them in a single expression* and report a corresponding error. — You can make the error message arbitrarily detailed, of course. But often there’s also no issue with reporting errors “piecemeal”, i.e. just stop at the first problem. End-user UIs should probably not do this, but for programming APIs this is completely conventional, and generally sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commenters have explained why you can't (easily) do what you want in base R.

The `checkmate` package allows you to do something similar to what you want.  Here's a variation of your code, with a couple of typos corrected.

```
library(checkmate)

simple_function <- function(x, y) {
  allErrors <- makeAssertCollection()
  assertNumeric(x, len = 1, add = allErrors)
  assertNumeric(y, len = 1, add = allErrors)
  
  sub_func(x, y, allErrors)
}

sub_func <- function(x, y, collection) {
  assertFALSE(x == 5, add = collection)
  reportAssertions(collection)
  
  ifelse(x > 5,  x * y, x + y)
}

a = 5
b = 'b'

simple_function(a, b) 

Error in simple_function(a, b) : 2 assertions failed:
* Variable 'y': Must be of type 'numeric', not 'character'.
* Variable 'x == 5': Must be FALSE.
```

However, in a more complex, real life example, allowing code to continue after errors have been detected is likely to lead to more complicated code.  I don't recommend allowing bad input to one function to be passed to others.